# How to launch file

Tags: ruby, windows, cmd

I need a reliable way to launch a file through ruby. If the file is an mp3, it will play, if it is a txt notepad will open and so on.
Basically I'm trying to use the `"folder\folder\filename"` behavior on the command line. The filename might contain spaces.
I tried a couple of things already, like:

```
´"folder\\example.txt"´      //With backsticks instead
```

but

```
Exec format error - "folder\example.txt" (Errno::ENOEXEC)
```

and

```
filename = "folder\\example.txt"
proc = Process.spawn "\"#{filename}\""
Process.detach(proc)
```

and

```
system "\"folder\\example.txt\""
```

that does nothing.

How can I launch a file from ruby?

**NEW INFO**
I tried to wrap the music name in " instead of the all name and it worked. But some folders have spaces, so this is not a solution. When start fails a new empty cmd opens for some reason.

Comment: What's your Operation System. In ruby you can execute comand line functions by embracing the comand over `\`` . Just like that: \`commnad\`

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1

Comment: On windows you can use start before the file path. Example: `\`start C:\\desenv\\textFile.txt\``

Comment: If I use start, a new cmd opens but still no file.

Comment: It's supposed to work specially followed by the file path. when you type any command under `\`` it executes the windows command line. try \``dir`\` and you will see the current directory files. I'm not a windows expert. can't help you after this point.

Comment: the windows `start` command is bad designed. The first parameter is taken as the title of the new process, if enclosed in quotes. Best practice: always give it a first parameter in quotes (if needed or not). It can be empty. Example: `start "" "c:\my directory\file.txt"`

Comment: @Stephan thanks, that worked perfectly. Would you like to write that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the windows start command is bad designed. The first parameter is taken as the title of the new process, if enclosed in quotes. Best practice: always give it a first parameter in quotes (if needed or not). It can be empty. Example:

```
start "" "c:\my directory\file.txt"
```

or

```
start "title" "c:\my directory\file.txt"
```

of course you won't see that title anywhere, as this will start notepad which does not support a "title".

Answer (score 0):

You can use, as an example the calculator on Windows:

puts ( "#{%x{calc}}" )